# pdftoppm "No display font" errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-7, xpdf, pdftoppm

I'm using pdftoppm to extract pages from a pdf file, so I can later convert the resulting pbm files into multi-page tiffs with ImageMagick.  I've got it to work using the following code:

```
os.system('pdftoppm -f %i -l %i -aa no -mono -q "%s" %sx' % (StartPage[item], EndPage[item], pdfname, wkgdir))
```

However, for each item I keep getting these errors even though I have the -q flag to prevent them being written to output:

> Error: No display font for 'Symbol'
>
> Error: No display font for 'Zapf Dingbats'

Is this a known bug with the program, or is there something else I should do to prevent these errors being printed, as they slow my program down?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try using:

```
'pdftoppm -f %i -l %i -aa no -mono -q "%s" %sx 2>/dev/null'
```

in your command-line string. That should prevent the stderror print.